# Programmatically created UIViewController partially hidden by navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that I create programmatically, without Interface Builder. The class is called `ColorController`, since it edits a color. When I add it to a popup inside a `UINavigationController`, its content is hidden under the navigation bar. This did not used to happen when the `ColorController` was pulled from the IB storyboard file.

Is there some property or method I must override on my `ColorController` to tell it to adjust its bounds when in a navigation controller?

Right now all I'm doing is creating my root `UIView` (a `ColorPicker`) and setting it as `self.view` in `loadView()`.

```
class ColorController: UIViewController {

    private let colorPicker: ColorPicker       

    init() {
        colorPicker = ColorPicker()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = colorPicker
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't override loadView, override viewDidLoad and add colorPicker self.view

Use SnapKit

```
colorPicker.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalTo(0)
    make.top.equalTo(self.topLayoutGuide.snp.bottom);
}
```

Use iOS UIKit

```
colorPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint(item: colorPicker, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                           NSLayoutConstraint(item: colorPicker, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                           NSLayoutConstraint(item: colorPicker, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)]

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: colorPicker, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
} else {
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: colorPicker, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
self.view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

Comment: This works. I can accept the answer, but it might be better if your example code used the iOS API instead of whatever 3rd party library this is.

Comment: Cool, thanks. There is a more convenient way to do it now using UIKit. Eg, `view.leadingArchor.constraintEqualTo(...)` and friends. But the way in the answer works on older versions of iOS.